# Astar can't get the optimal solution

Tags: a-star

As shown in the figure, based on the connotation of Astar, the point closer to the end point will be preferred, so the optimal path cannot be obtained.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKSE.png

Comment: A correct version of A* wouldn't *permanently* take those detours, it would explore them yes, but then discard them as it find out that they are detours. Please add some code so that we have the opportunity to find a mistake in it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting diagonal edges with the same length as horizontal/vertical edges, in which case this is a correct solution.